# sed : difference between " sed 's/\-.*// " & " sed '/\-/s/\-.*//gw "

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I am learning few simple `sed` commands.

Command #1

```
sed 's/\-.*//gw without' tgs.txt
```

Command #2

```
sed '/\-/s/\-.*//gw with' tgs.txt
```

Output #1

```
$ cat with
2. Databases 
6. Windows
 Raja
```

Output #2

```
$ cat without 
2. Databases 
6. Windows
 Raja
```

Difference Between them

```
$ diff with without 
$
```

What's the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between these in effect:

```
sed 's/\-.*//g'
sed '/\-/s/\-.*//g'
```

The first form acts on *all* lines, the second form acts only on those lines which match `/-/` [using addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses). Since the action taken includes `-`, in effect both lines will only affect those which contain `-`.

Now if you'd used `/Raja/` as an address instead, you'd only have seen the last line in `with` - that is, only those lines which contained `Raja`, and had the substitution performed.

Comment: I mentioned Globally , so It have to perform on all the lines with `-` matching only. If no match then It wont do anything right. I am more curious about special meaning of second command '/\-/'

Comment: @Raja in the second case, yes, what you said is correct. But the `g` acts on the `s`, not on the address, so it is not affecting which lines are edited. The meaning of that initial `/-/` is "act on only those lines which match `-`".

Comment: @muru, you are correct. But still a question from a beginner in sed. Why `sed 's/-.*//g'` and `sed 's/\-.*//g'` produce the same result.

Comment: @g_p As far as I know `-` is not [a special character in BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03). The standard says using `\-` when `-` is not special results in undefined behaviour, but most programs treat them as the same. Special characters like `^.$*`, on the other hand, are a different case.

Comment: I have executed few combination on an online shell emulator(I am sitting in front of  a window machine with lots of restriction) and its behaviour is confusing me. I will try it later. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @muru `-` is not a special character in any regex notations unless when it's used inside the character class.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Even then only if it is not the first or last character.

Comment: @muru `The first form acts on all lines, the second form acts only on those lines which match /-/` it' swrong.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh?

Comment: i think you mean the same what i mean.

Answer (score 3):

These two sed commands,

```
sed 's/\-.*//g'
sed '/\-/s/\-.*//g'
```

will do the same job. Let me explain how..

```
sed 's/\-.*//g'
```

will replace all the characters from `-` to the last character with an empty string. If a line don't have any `-` character then the replacement won't occur. That is, it won't affect the lines which don't have the hyphen `-` symbol.

```
sed '/\-/s/\-.*//g'
```

will first search for the lines which have the `-` symbol. If it finds any, then it will do the replacement (replaces all the characters from `-` to the last character with an empty string) on those lines.

So both are the **same**. Your first sed command would be enough. You don't need to put the search condition. Also, since `-` is not a special character, you don't need to escape it.

Comment: Nice answer. Surprised to see it as not accepted.